# How can I fix the parser error in this code?

Tags: python

```
from scipy.stats import poisson 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

    def get_premier_league_data(start_year):
    season = str(start_year)[-2:] + str(start_year + 1)[-2:]
    data = pd.read_csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/" + season + "/E0.csv") 
    return data

    data = get_premier_league_data(2018)
data.head()
```

Comment: What parser error? Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. The code should be a [mre].

Comment: Hi, knowing the error, what is it, where is it? Cleaning your code to the essential parts as well.

Answer (score 0):

Fix this `line` you geeting `Parser error` because you have some bad lines in `Data` .. i've tested know it's working. Just add `on_bad_lines='skip'` [reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
data = pd.read_csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/" + season + "/E0.csv" , on_bad_lines='skip')
```

complete code

```
from scipy.stats import poisson 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

def get_premier_league_data(start_year):
    season = str(start_year)[-2:] + str(start_year + 1)[-2:]
    data = pd.read_csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/" + season + "/E0.csv" , on_bad_lines='skip') 
    return data

data = get_premier_league_data(2018)
print(data.head())
```

output#

```
                                              <HTML>
0                                             <HEAD>
1  <TITLE>Football Betting | Football Results | F...
2     <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
3    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@12Xpert" />
4  <meta name="twitter:title" content="Football-D...
```